# Eclipse - how do I hide all of these files?

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, ide

So I recently tried to download e(fx)clipse and then deleted it - for some reason this popped up? Rather than the standard view where you see the src, lib, and then the Java standard libraries, I'm seeing a long list of files - Does anyone know what's going on / how to fix? thanks!

[image: [Image Here]]

I tried to fix the perspective / shuffle around configure build path but I'm just not experienced enough with Java to figure it out!

Comment: _tried to download e(fx)clipse_ Does that mean that you did not succeed in downloading it? _and then deleted it_ So you did manage to download it successfully? So if you deleted it, then what is the screen capture an image of?

Comment: That list is "modules", not files (they are all in jrt-fs.jar if you look carefully). This is just the standard module list for Java and is completely normal, you don't need to do anything. Newer versions of Java are different internally from older versions you might have seen in the past.

Answer (score 2):

It seems **you are confusing** the ***Projects*** view with the ***Project Explorer*** view or the *Package Explorer* view.

The ***Projects* view alone does not make sense** (as shown in your screenshot), only together with the *Packages*, *Types* and *Members* views the *Projects* view makes sense, like in the [***Java Browsing* perspective**](https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-Browsing.htm).

Make sure you are in the right perspective (*Window > Perspective > Open Perspective > ...*) or reset the perspective  (*Window > Perspective > Reset Perspective*) or close the *Projects* view and open the *Project Explorer* view instead (*Window > Show View > Project Explorer*).